# Firefox mobile Add-on SDK error message missing

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, adb, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using creating extension for mobile firefox using Addon SDK (1.17). I have a problem with displaying error messages in console.

To load extension I use this command:
`cfx run -a fennec-on-device -b adb --mobile-app firefox --force-mobile`

For displaying messages use: `adb logcat | grep console`

The result looks like this:

```
I/Gecko   ( 3612): console.log: extension-name: *** extension loaded ***
I/stdout  ( 3612): console.log: extension-name: *** extension loaded  ***
I/Gecko   ( 3612): console.error: extension-name: 
I/stdout  ( 3612): console.error: extension-name: 
I/Gecko   ( 3612): console.log: extension-name: message text
I/stdout  ( 3612): console.log: extension-name: message text
```

It is really annoying to find the bug.

Does anybody know, what how to make error message appear?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you resolve this by any chance @dakov?